# How can I force only two selection out of 5 available on slicer visual?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Can someone please help me get a fix for this please.

[image]

I want to let people make only two selection at a time, no more no less from the given options. The intention is to get data on matrix dynamic column based on these two selections.

Thanks
Avi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a feature of a slicer visual, but I don't know of any built-in or custom slicer visual that does this.

As a workaround you can show a warning and instruction to select two items, eg a big Card visual with red text and a transparent background in front of your other visuals displaying a measure like:

```
AreTwoCategoriesSelected =
IF (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( DimProductCategory[ProductCategoryName] ) <> 2,
    "Select 2 Categories for this report",
    ""
)
```

Which might look like

[image]

and

[image]

You can't easily use the trick where you have the measure conditionally return BLANK because most evaluations of the measure will have a filter context with just one of the selected values.

Answer (score 1):

You did not make clear what the purpose of this exercise is and how the result should look like ("get data on matrix dynamic column"), but you could

1. Create 2 single selection slicers based on copies of your category column
2. Make sure they are not related to the rest of your data model
3. Get the selected rows via the SELECTEDVALUE() function

You may have to consider the case where both selections are the same.